# How to link paraview filter details between views?

Tags: paraview

When I split a layout into two render views, all filters in the pipeline are separated, e.g. a StreamTracer's source properties. How can I link those? In Tools -> Manage Links... I can only link the views themselves, or some properties, but I cannot find the proper way to link filters from the pipeline.

A wild guess was linking the GeometryRepresentation, but a first quick test did not achieve anything...

---

Also asked at https://discourse.paraview.org/t/how-to-link-paraview-filter-details-between-views/7020

Comment: This question is more related to a specific feature of ParaView than Scientific Visualization. I think that [ParaView Discourse site](https://discourse.paraview.org/) is a better place for this question.

Comment: @nicoguaro Good point, thanks, I'll ask there as well. But instead of purely closing, can you migrate this question to StackOverflow? This question is truly rather technical on second thought